# iOS using NSOperationQueue and AFNetworking to implement multi-download feature

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am using NSOperationQueue and AFNetworking to implement a multi-download feature for my project. I also use Core Data to persist downloaded information but I am OK with that part. My problem is when it comes to actually create the download tasks. So here is how I did that:

```
// create a NSOperationQueue
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.name = @"DownloadQueue";
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

// create an operation (AFDownloadRequestOperation is a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation)
AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = // some initializations

// add the operation to the queue
[queue addOperation:operation];

// later some more operations are created and added to the queue
```

Then say I added 3 operations to the queue. Since I set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1, so only 1 operation in the queue is running, the other 2 are waiting:

```
operation 1: running
operation 2: waiting
operation 3: waiting
```

Then I use `pause`(which is a method of `AFURLConnectionOperation`) to pause the operation that is running, and I expect to see one of the 2 waiting operations start running, but it does not happen, the 2 waiting operations remain waiting:

```
operation 1: paused
operation 2: waiting
operation 3: waiting
```

I still have to resume operation 1 and wait till it finishes, then operation 2 or 3 will start running.

My question is how to make the other operations in the queue running after I pause a running operation like I explained above?

Also, I would appreciate it very much if you could explain a better way to implement multi-downloading (specifically related to manage the max number of download tasks, pause/resume a download task)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Simply use `cancel` to pause an operation (You will need to handle the situation when the cancel flag is "YES" in your operation to actually let the operation quit). Then all the operations in the queue behaviors as I expected (cancel one operation, then another waiting one gets to run)

And when you need to resume downloading, simply create a new operation that fetches contents from web to the same local file path. (with the help of `AFDownloadRequestOperation`, resuming downloading works well)

Now my multi downloading system works well, comment if you need info about implementation.